# Pygments command line not syntax highlighting HTML output

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, command-line-tool, pygments

I am trying to take a python script and prepare it for paper printing with syntax highlighting and line numbering. I have used the following command line instruction:

```
pygmentize -f html -O style=colored,linenos=1 -l python -o <file>.html <file>.py
```

This instruction runs without errors but no matter how I indicate the style and the lexer, the output HTML never has syntax highlighting at all. It is appropriately formatted with correct indentation and line numbers, but I cannot get it to match the coloured syntax highlighting displayed when using the [pygments demo](https://pygments.org/demo/), or any colours.

I have also tried different aliases of python (such as `py`, `python3` and `py3`) and different styles, but the HTML is always the same. For what it's worth, I am using PowerShell on Windows 10 to run the instruction and Google Chrome to view the output HTML (though I have also checked with Edge and don't see any difference).

Comment: I would also like an answer to this question. I was running this on Linux, so maybe this is a pygmentize issue? For what its worth using the python module instead of the pygmentize CLI did work (so maybe its a bug in the CLI?): 
pygments.highlight(
    open(fpath, 'r').read(),
    lexer=pygments.lexers.get_lexer_by_name('python'),
    formatter=pygments.formatters.html.HtmlFormatter(
        noclasses=True,
        style=pygments.styles.get_style_by_name('default')
    )
)

Answer (score 6):

While writing my above comment, I actually found the solution. I dug into the javascript code to find the actual python call to make the python implementation work. In that notice how there is a noclasses=True as a formatter option.

I have no idea what noclasses does, but if you add it to the CLI as a formatter option then the output is colored correctly:

```sh
pygmentize -l python -f html -O style=default -O noclasses=True -o <file>.html <file>.py
```

Comment: The default (without noclasses) outputs HTML elements with solely a classname so that using CSS one can apply styling to the fragments. `noclasses` changes that behaviour to write the styles inline into the HTML element definitions.

Comment: all you really need is -O noclasses=True looks like, thanks!